# Tex dash ligatures in TT family with Lualatex

Tags: luatex, typewriter

I'm just playing around, trying to get Latex output like what I used see from a typewriter. (I know about typewriter.sty.) I'm using `\ttfamily` and Lualatex.

Is there any way to get the Tex ligatures `---` for em dash to produce two hyphens in tt family (and `--` to produce one hyphen)? I know I could work around it by using macros, but that makes the source harder to read.

This is just for fun, I have no real need for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
Would like to see---in tt family---em dashes as two hyphens,
and en dashes as one hyphen: 1--2.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
function tthyph(s)
 return string.gsub(s,'[-][-]','\string\\mbox{-}')
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer',tthyph,'tt dashes')
}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
Would like to see---in tt family---em dashes as two hyphens,
and en dashes as one hyphen: 1--2.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Don't understand it, but it works great!

Comment: @dedded it is just doing a text replace of `--` to `\mbox{-}`  before normal tex processing, so `1--2` is `1\mbox{-}2` and `a---b` is `a\mbox{-}-b`  the mbox stopping the latter making an n-dash ligature

Comment: Is 'tt hashes' just a comment?

Comment: not just a comment as it can be used to add and remove callbacks, so more a "meaningfull identifier" you can not distinguish function definitions all functions "look the same"  see `texdoc ltluatex` @dedded (also hashes was probably a typo for dashes as hashes makes no sense, I'll fix:-)